# How do I get specific values from a DOMXPath query?

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath, domxpath

I am new on DOMXPath but I am trying to learn more. Currently I have a HTML structure like this:

```
    <span class="1">
        <div class="headerClass">
            Here you have <span class="spanClass1">some text</span>. And here there is <span class="spanClass2">even more text</span>
        </div>
        <table class="tableClass" id="tableID">
            <tr>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td>some text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.website1.com" target="_blank">My Link</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.website2.com" target="_blank">My Link</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </span>

    <span class="2">
        <div class="headerClass">
            Here you have <span class="spanClass1">some text</span>. And here there is <span class="spanClass2">even more text</span>
        </div>
        <table class="tableClass" id="tableID">
            <tr>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td>some text</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.website1.com" target="_blank">My Link</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td>some text</td>
                <td><a href="http://www.website2.com" target="_blank">My Link</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </span>

... and the spans continue: 3, 4, 5 ... etc
```

To retrieve this HTML code from the source file, I am using this:

```
$oDomXpath = new DOMXpath($oDom);
$query = "//span[number(@class)=number(@class)]";   
$oDomObject = $oDomXpath->query($query);

foreach ($oDomObject as $oObject) {
    // WHAT GOES HERE????
}
```

I need to store in an array the following values:

1. The plain text of all `<div class="headerClass">` without the html tags.
2. The text of all `<span class="spanClass2">`
3. All the url's inside the tables. Tables can have any number of rows from 0 to many.

How can I accomplish this? What would I have to put inside the foreach loop? Do I need to necessarily run another query??

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the choice, you can use several XPath queries and obtain values one by one, or you can build an unique XPath query with several paths:

```
<pre><?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('yourfile.html');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$xquery = <<<'EOD'
//span[number(@class)=@class]/@class |
//span[number(@class)=@class]/div[@class='headerClass'] |
//span[number(@class)=@class]/div[@class='headerClass']/span[@class='spanClass2'] | 
//span[number(@class)=@class]/table[@class='tableClass']/tr/td/a
EOD;

$nodes = $xpath->query($xquery);

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeType == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)
        switch($node->nodeName):
            case 'div' : echo '<br/>div content: ' . $node->nodeValue; break;
            case 'span': echo '<br/>span content: ' . $node->nodeValue; break;
            default    : echo '<br/>url: ' . $node->getAttribute('href');
        endswitch;
    else
        echo '<br/><br/>number: ' . $node->value;
}
```